# Azure cosmosDB: Getting error on sorting with mongoDB api

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using MongoDB API.

```
  if (req.query.sortBy) {
    var parts = req.query.sortBy.split(":");
    sort[parts[0]] = parts[1] === "desc" ? -1 : 1;
  }
  try {
    // var tasks = await Task.find({owner:req.user._id})
    // res.send(tasks)
    await req.user
      .populate({
        path: "tasks",
        options: {
          limit: parseInt(req.query.limit),
          skip: parseInt(req.query.skip),
          sort,
        },
      })
      .execPopulate();
```

This is working perfectly to do sortBy=createdAt_asc or sortBy=createdAt_desc on the MongoDB on my localhost.
But getting an error when using the cosmosDB connection.
the error is

```
Error=2, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 471da3a5-0085-4b62-a447-c8bb1b26dded; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 471da3a5-0085-4b62-a447-c8bb1b26dded; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 471da3a5-0085-4b62-a447-c8bb1b26dded; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 471da3a5-0085-4b62-a447-c8bb1b26dded; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 471da3a5-0085-4b62-a447-c8bb1b26dded; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["The index path corresponding to the specified order-by item is excluded."]}\r\n` +
    'ActivityId: 471da3a5-0085-4b62-a447-c8bb1b26dded, Request URI: /apps/fdd31784-70ac-4bdd-b379-098c33c600e2/services/0b9a2cb6-44f8-45b7-bef9-cbfa6e5673e5/partitions/28daf003-696b-4ce3-ad83-5572e94bbff8/replicas/132429018129211375s/, RequestStats: Please see CosmosDiagnostics, SDK: Windows/10.0.14393 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.3.2);););););',
  code: 2,
  codeName: 'BadValue',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Can you share the indexes you have defined in Cosmos for this collection?

Answer (score 0):

Searching that error messages turns up [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-troubleshoot), which points to the solution as fixing the [indexing policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy) on your container. Please ensure you aren't excluding the path you're querying against.

Comment: That index policy only applies to SQL API. Mongo has it's own indexing.